# When does(Time) Intentservice start?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am trying to figure out the flow of instructions in Android and I wrote the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "This is the ------------------- Start Line");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeCheckService.class);
        startService(intent);
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.");
        }
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.close();
    }
```

The logcat output is

```
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This is the ------------------- Start Line
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:05.742: D/MainActivity(1462): This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.
08-29 23:00:07.502: D/IsContactEmpty(1462): Starting IsContactEmpty
08-29 23:00:09.162: D/IsContactEmpty(1462): End IsContactEmpty
08-29 23:00:09.162: D/TimeCheckService(1462): Contacts not Empty
```

Now the timestamp in logcat shows that `IntentService` was executed at `23:00:07.502`  after the all the code in *MainActivity* is executed, where as according to the sequence of MainActivity `IntentService` should have been started earlier and executed in parallel? Can someone explain this please?

The code for `IsContactEmpty`

```
public class IsContactEmpty {
    public static final String TAG = "IsContactEmpty";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void isContactsEmpty() {

    }

    public static boolean valueOf(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting IsContactEmpty");
        boolean isEmpty;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            isEmpty = false;
        } else {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "End IsContactEmpty");
        return isEmpty;
    }
}
```

I replaced `IntentService` with a `Thread` as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "This is the ------------------- Start Line");

        new ChkServiceThread().start();

        //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeCheckService.class);
        //startService(intent);
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This line is to check the________________________ sequence of execeution in Android.");
        }
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.close();
    }

    private class ChkServiceThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean isEmpty = IsContactEmpty.valueOf(MainActivity.this);

            if ( isEmpty == true ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Contacts Empty");

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Contacts not Empty");
                // mHandler.post(new DisplayToast("Contacts Ok", this));
            }

        }

    }
```

and ran application 10 times but the result remains the exactly same as shown the previous logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IntentService` and your `MainActivity` run in the same process. All lifecycle calls in Activities and Services like `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStartCommand()` run on the main thread. So it is impossible for anything to happen in the Service on the main thread until the `onCreate()` call of `MainActivity` completes.

Comment: Thanks, then creating a `Thread` instead of `IntentService` should make a difference?

Comment: If you create a Thread, it will start as soon as it can. But it can and will run in parallel with the main thread. There just is no guarantee how soon it will start. It depends on the thread priority algorithm of the virtual machine.

Comment: You can also start your IntentService in another process. Then it will also run in parallel with your activities. Managing a remote service can be a bit more complicated though. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what `IsContactEmpty` does. What is it you are trying to do? What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Well, as I said before. There is no guarantee as to when the thread will run. As I asked before: What is it you are trying to do? What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: If you just want to force the thread to run you can add `Thread.sleep(500)` to `MainActivity.onCreate()` after the call to `ChkServiceThread().start()`. But in general you don't want to block the main thread like that.

Comment: I am trying to find if the contact book of user is empty or does it have nay contact, second and most important to understand is how Android works.

Comment: Well, I hope my answer was helpful. If so, you can accept it. If you want to so something asynchronously you should request that some asynchronous process (a service, a thread, an AsyncTask, whatever) cehck the state of the contacts and call your activity back with some results. You can put up a dialog telling the user that you are checking his contacts and when the callback comes you can dismiss the dialog and display the results.

Comment: Thanks David, you answer was helpful, I am upvoting it but would like to keep it open for others to answer.